# Is Zero valid for a PathVariable?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

Using a Spring RestController I have the following mapping setup:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/question/{orderformid}/{qstnum}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

But when I have this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/question/5477bdf6153d38c711074083/0
```

I get an error for qstnum:

> Missing URI template variable 'qstNum' for method parameter of type
>   int

Is it not valid to have zero for a path variable?

Comment: what is your method signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 is a valid value. You probably have wrong signature of the controller method.

> Missing URI template variable 'qstNum' for method parameter of type int

Based on this you probably have something like `@PathVariable int qstNum` in your controller method. But that expects the placeholder in request mapping to be also named `qstNum` not `qstnum` (notice the case).

So you could change the variable to `@PathVariable int qstnum`, rename placeholder to `{qstNum}` or explicitly specify the placeholder name in `PathVariable` like so: `@PathVariable("qstnum") int qstNum`.

Comment: that was it... yeesh, what a forehead slapper.